# Disallowed generic array creation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I thought I understood that you could not create arrays of generic classes in Java but a few examples I have seen lately have really confused me. Can someone explain? Thanks!

I have a generic class defined as: `public class Bag<Item> implements Iterable<Item>`

Now in a class called EdgeWeightedGraph (below), I am making an array of Bag and that's compiling just fine. If Bag wasn't a generic class, I know that this should have been fine but here, it is. Then why is the compiler not throwing an error?

```
public class EdgeWeightedGraph {

private final int V;
private final Bag[] adj;

    public EdgeWeightedGraph(int V) {
        this.V = V;
        adj = new Bag[V];
    }
}
```

While it is throwing an error in another generic class defined as:

```
public class MinPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {

private Key[] pq;

    public MinPQ() {
        pq = new Key[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `EdgeWeightedGraph`, this line does not create a generic array.

```
adj = new Bag[V];
```

It is creating an array of a raw type, which is allowed.  `Bag` is a class, not a type parameter.

However, in `MinPQ`, `Key` is a type parameter, not a class, so this line attempts to create a generic array and is a compiler error.

```
pq = new Key[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

`Bag` is a raw type. It is not generic. A generic type is for instance `Bag<Integer>`.

So the following compiles:

```
adj = new Bag[V];  // compiles
```

but the following doesn't

```
adj = new Bag<Integer>[V]; // error
```

As for `Key`, it is a type parameter, not a raw type like `Bag`.